# Java - get the value of selected list item

Tags: java, sql, database, eclipse, user-interface

how can I get the value of an list?

This are my two lists and after selecting these two values from the list(as marked) I want to insert these two elements(strings) into my database at this postition in my code:

```
                PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query);

                pst.setString(1, txtFieldName.getText());
                pst.setString(2, txtFieldNumber.getText());
            //  pst.setString(3, listDay.);
```

And at the last position I want to select the value which the user selects in the UI two list :

[image: Picture list]

`JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Speichern");
        btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                try {`

    `java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dblabor","root",""); 
String query = "INSERT INTO Teach(Prof,Laborname,Room,Day,Time) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query);`

```
                pst.setString(1, txtFieldName.getText());
                pst.setString(2, txtFieldLaborname.getText());
                pst.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(txtFieldRoom.getText()));
                pst.setString(4, (String) listDay.getSelectedValue());
                pst.setString(5, (String) listTime.getSelectedValue());
                pst.execute();
                pst.close();


                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Succssesfull");


            }

            catch(Exception e1) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong");


            }
```

`

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: (1-) `pst.setObject(4, listTag.getSelectedValue()); nothing happens` - define "nothing happens". Did you print the value? Do you get an SQL error? Something happens but we can't tell anything from the code you posted. So unless you can provide details we can't help.

Comment: @camickr, I  am sorry, after clicking to the button nothing happens, no error, and no printed value.

Comment: You still haven't answered my question!!!. Did you print the value of the seleted item???? The value will either be null or it will be what you expect. Did you step through the code???? Did you create an SQL statement? Did you execute the SQL statement? Did you check the return code of the SQL. Did you get the data from the ResultSet??? Something happens, you just haven't done any debugging. We can't see your SQL statement, so we don't know if that is the problem. We can't see your try/catch block so we don't know it that is a problem.  We don't even know what you expect will happen.

Comment: We don't even know if you added an ActionListener to the button. Post a  proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @camickr , Im sorry, I am new here trying to do everything correct. I edit my question.

Comment: You still haven't stated what happens!!!!!! Did you print the selected value???? What do you see??? When you run the code what do you see??? I see that you display an option panel whether the query works or not, so what do you see??? Don't display "wrong" when it doesn't work. You want to display the error message otherwise how do you know how to fix the problem.???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I get the value of an list?

You have been told to simply use:

```
Object value = list.getSelectedValue();
System.out.println(value);
```

Did you display the value?

Have you read the tutorial on [JDBC Database Access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html)?

I believe you need to use `executeUpate()` method of the `PreparedStatement` to change the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Swing, try method [`javax.swing.JList#getSelectedValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValue--) to get value from JList object.

Comment: thx for your answer. When I try this `pst.setObject(4, listTag.getSelectedValue());` nothing happens